# How many non-negative integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 28$ are there with $x_{1} \leq 6, x_{2} \leq 10, x_{3} \leq 15, x_{4} \leq21$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many non-negative integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 28$ are there with $x_{1} \leq 6, x_{2} \leq 10, x_{3} \leq 15, x_{4} \leq21$?

Attempt:

$x_{1} \geq 7$

$x_{2} \geq 11$

$x_{3} \geq 16$

$x_{4} \geq 22$

$N(U)$ = ${28 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_1)$ = ${28-7 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_2)$ = ${28-11 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_3)$ = ${28-16 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_4)$ = ${28-22 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_1\cap x_2)$ = ${28-7-11 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_1\cap x_3)$ = ${28-7-16 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_1\cap x_4)$ = ${28-7-22 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_2\cap x_3)$ = ${28-11-16 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_2\cap x_4)$ = ${28-11-22 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

$N(x_3\cap x_4)$ = ${28-11-22 + 4 - 1 \choose 4-1}$

Answer = $N(U) - N(x_1) - N(x_2) -N(x_3) -N(x_4)+  N(x_1\cap x_2)+  N(x_1\cap x_3)+  N(x_1\cap x_4)+  N(x_2\cap x_3)+  N(x_2\cap x_4)+  N(x_3\cap x_4)$

Comment: Your solution is correct.  Note that $N(x_2 \cap x_4) = 0$ and $N(x_3 \cap x_4) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use generating functions. For $x_1$ you get
$$
1 +x + \ldots x^6 = \frac{x^7-1}{x-1}
$$
and for the rest of the variables similarly, and then you need to find the coefficient of $x^{28}$ in the product of these 4 generating functions...

Comment: Is my method wrong? My teacher did a similar question with this method.

Comment: @NoName not wrong, you can do it that way -- but this is a very common alternative.

Comment: Do I have to subtract (or add?) N(x1∩x2∩x3)?

Comment: @NoName: Yes, in principle you must then subtract $N(x_1 \cap x_2 \cap x_3)$ and also for all the other three-way combinations, and then add back the four-way combination. But already $x_1 \cap x_2 \cap x_3$ (using your imprecise notation) is empty in this case, so you don't need to worry. You do need to worry in general (in other problems) though, and the observation that in this case they are empty IS PART OF THE ANSWER.